What do wet, ash, ask, ASL... have in common?
Wet, ash, ask, ASL, BBC, sad, [fig, kiss]*, rope, put, gas, has, top, lad, TRIP.
*:Not true universally

Are fig/kiss correct?

@noedne it depends, I can't say the reason though because that is a huge hint for the answer, I'll edit it to be more universal. And yes I did the puzzle myself

Please do not edit meta-information/non-puzzle content into your question, especially after it has a satisfactory answer.

All of these words

can be typed using only one row on a Turkish keyboard.



This is because

the Turkish alphabet has both a dotless I appearing in the QWERTY row like usual and a dotted I appearing at the end of the ASDF row.


That is correct!

Aha - I even rot13(ybbxrq sbe bgure xrlobneq ynlbhgf ohg fxvzzrq cnfg barf jurer V fnj V va gur hfhny cynpr)!

@aschepler But you also need that one for the last word! :-)
